# Action cable not working I have to refresh both the tab to see message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is code of room.coffee :

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
  connected: -> 
  disconnected: -> 

  received: (data) ->
    $('#messages').append "<p>#{data}</p>"    

  speak: (message) ->
    @perform 'speak' , message: message
```

cable.coffee :

```
@App ||= {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

rooms.coffee:

```
$ ->
    $messages = $('messages')
    $messages.scrollTop $messages.prop('scrollHieght')
    $('#message_input').focus()

$(document).on 'keypress','message_input','e'->
    if e.keycode == 13 and e.target.value
    App.room.speak(e.target.value)
    e.target.value = ''
    e.preventDefault()
```

roomchannel:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     stream_from "room_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def speak(data)
    message.create content: data['message']
  end
end
```

Broadcostmessage:

```
 def perform(message)
    Actioncable.server.broadcast 'room_channel',render_message(message)
  end
  private
  def render_message(message)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render_message
  end
```

when create the new message it will not automatically load  all the messages of my browser untill the page in not reload.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try including cable.coffee/js in the room view.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'cable', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

You'll want to add cable.js to /config/initializers/assets.rb as well.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( cable.js )
```

Comment: Default application already reloads all the javascripts and cable is part of this.

Answer (score 0):

This old question that came up in a Google search, but did anyone mention the typo in:

```
$messages.scrollTop $messages.prop('scrollHieght')
```

That should be:

```
$messages.scrollTop $messages.prop('scrollHeight')
```